# Make apps download to other drives than C

Tags: windows, ssd, storage

The C: drive on my laptop is almost full. The other 2 drives still have a lot of space left in them. How can I make new apps or files download to other drives without any problems automatically?
I need apps that require a lot of space(Davinci Resolve, blender, houdini), so I kind of need to move some apps to other drives.
(Im using windows 11)

Comment: Can’t you just uninstall and reinstall these applications to your desired drive?

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://support.msecure.com/en/support/solutions/articles/36000130212-install-or-move-microsoft-store-apps-on-separate-drive) link describes how to change the default installation path for new Microsoft Store apps and also how to move existing apps.

It can all be done in the Windows settings (press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>).

To change the default installation path for MS Store apps:

```
System > Storage > Save locations > new apps will save to
```

To move existing apps:

```
System > Apps & features > (select your app) > Move
```

The default download path for files downloaded from the web can be changed in the browser. [This](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/where-find-and-manage-downloaded-files-firefox#w_change-where-downloads-are-saved) is the guide for Mozilla Firefox. [This](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95759) one is for Google Chrome (click on "Change download locations").

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Zomega's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1767925/141909), you should also tell your browser to not automatically download, but to ask for the download location first, and/or change the default download location. Google for "*browsername* download location".

There are more things you can do - there are plenty of questions on this site about [low C: disk space](https://superuser.com/search?q=is%3Aq+c%3A+disk+space). One thing I definitely suggest is going through each of your installed programs and see if you can change their data locations to another partition. (You don't need to *need to move some apps to other drives*, you need to move their data.)

Ultimately, this won't 'save' you, Windows and other updates will keep consuming disk space.

It is unclear from your question how much physical drives you have.

If you have only one (probably, since it's a laptop), take a look at software that lets you resize partitions. You can then increase C: at the cost of decreasing the other partitions.

If you actually have different physical drives, prepare for replacing the C: disk with a larger one.